# How to return value from the TK toplevel window?

Tags: return, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a TCL script that opens a TK toplevel window. In this window the user can manipulate some widgets (buttons that call other procedures to do some work, checkbuttons, etc.). When user is finished, I want him to click a button in this window that would cause the toplevel to be destroyed and the procedure that opened it to return a value. Here is what I've got:

```
proc openWindow {} {
    set w .testwindow
    catch {destroy $w}
    toplevel $w

    <here I setup all the widgets of the window>

    button $w.btn -text "Exit" -command {
        set ret [finishTest]
        puts "returning $ret"
        return $ret
    }

    pack $w.btn
    pack $w
}

proc finishTest {} {
    <here I evaluate the state of the $w widgets>
    if {some condition} {
        destroy $w
        return 0
    } else {
        destroy $w
        return -1
    }
}
```

when I call openWindow, the window displays and behaves as it should, when I click the Exit button, it correctly prints "returning: $ret" but whan I call puts [openWindow] it only prints a new line with no other characters after I click the button.

I defined the $w variable globaly so that I can access it outside the openWindow in the finishTest procedure.

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callbacks can't affect local variables, and your `openWindow` isn't currently waiting for the callback to process before returning. To make it work, you instead have to use `vwait` (or `tkwait`) to let the event loop run until the callback is performed. (It does this by running a subsidiary event loop, which does take stack space, so watch out for reentrancy problems.) Check out the marked lines below (your `finishTest` is unchanged).

```
proc openWindow {} {
    global ret;                                #########################
    set w .testwindow
    catch {destroy $w}
    toplevel $w

    <here I setup all the widgets of the window>

    button $w.btn -text "Exit" -command {
        set ret [finishTest];                  #########################
    }

    pack $w.btn
    pack $w
    vwait ret;                                 #########################
    puts "returning $ret";                     #########################
    return $ret;                               #########################
}
```

It's possible to untangle this mess somewhat with Tcl 8.6's coroutines, provided the call into `openWindow` can be done from inside a [coroutine](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/coroutine.htm) (i.e., a suspendable stack context). That would make this part of the code look more like (pay attention to marked lines again):

```
proc openWindow {} {
    set w .testwindow
    catch {destroy $w}
    toplevel $w

    <here I setup all the widgets of the window>

    button $w.btn -text "Exit" -command [info coroutine];   #########################

    pack $w.btn
    pack $w
    yield;                                                  #########################
    set ret [finishTest];                                   #########################
    puts "returning $ret";                                  #########################
    return $ret;                                            #########################
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Donal, this fixed my issue with returning a value from proc! However, as I stated in the answer to Hoodiecrow, I have to use a non-standard interpreter with Tcl/Tk8.3 that behaves totally differently than Wish. It doesent let me interact with the widgets, I can move or resize the window, but nothing inside reacts to anything. I know this is probably a whole different question than I asked originally, but If you have a suggestion, I would appretiate it, thank you! :)